# VBA can't set date format on column

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to change column format from "Custom" to "Date" by

```
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "Date"
```

but it set's F column's format just to another Custom, and for example

```
05 / 16
```

becomes to

```
1at2016
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: There is no need to select cells to work with them. Adjusting @Romi's answer: `Columns("F:F").NumberFormat = "mm/dd"`

Answer (score 3):

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd"
```

that should do the trick.

Comment: I've tried that way but the problem is that external cells are changing but the content stays the same. by clicking on "05/16" cell, "01.05.2016" can be seen in formula bar.. so that looks like I haven't changed the format... so we can see the changes only externally, but in the formula bar the same 01.05.2016 stays.. i need to get 05/16 to be shown in formula bar.